# What is difference between Xcode Ad Hoc and IOS Team Provisionig Profile

Tags: ios, xcode

I am not sure what is the difference between these two **XC Ad Ho**c and **iOS Team Provisionig Profile**. These two are generated by Xcode.

Are these two same? 
OR
If different what's difference between them and when to use which one?

As far as I understand  and searched the forum what I got is this

**Development** profile allows you to test your apps on your physical devices

**App Store Distribution** profile allows you to sign your apps for App Store distribution

**Ad Hoc Distribution** profile allows you to sign your apps for Ad Hoc distribution

Answer (score 1):

- Mainly AdHoc distribution allows you to install the generated IPA on
  100 devices which you can distribute for testing.This 100 devices
  should be added in your developer account.
- AdHoc distribution is used for testing production push notifications
  in the app. Before releasing the app to appstore, if you want test
  your production push notifications you need to generate ipa and test
  the notifications.

Answer (score 1):

**Ad Hoc Distribution Profile:** Using this profile you can allow 100 devices to install your app for testing purpose. App signed using this profile can be install using itunes. App must have same identifier as mentioned in Ad Hoc provision profile. ie. com.yourName.appName

**iOS Development Provision Profile:** You can install your app directly from XCode to test on device. It is not compulsory to have matching identifier for app and provision profile if provision profile is signed with wild card. ie. com.yourName.*